# Math puzzle, level 92: 21,17=104

Tags: mathematics, pattern

I stumbled upon the sequence ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMFJS.jpg)):

```
21,17=104
33,10=81
12,18=100
37,27=?
```

The answer is 170, but I'm curious about the rule behind it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an easy one, I think

> $$a,b = a + 5b - 2$$

So we have

> $$37, 27 = 37 + 5 \times 27 - 2 = 170$$

Always check

> Linear combinations first

Comment: Damn, I spent two days on this :_) Thank you so much!